# How to keep cloned field value after POST in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel for my app. That is having clonable fields. If validation fails form is reading and losing its value for all cloned fields. It is working fine for the normal field but all the cloned fields.

> Keeping code smaller, I have posted only two clonable fields, in fact,
> the clone group has about 5 fields.

```
<select name="next_station_id[]"
        class="select2 next-station-select cloner-field form-control @error('next_station_id') is-invalid @enderror"
        required>
    <option>Select Next Station</option>
    @foreach($stationsData as $id => $name)
        <option value="{{$id}}"
            {{ (isset($route) && $route->station->id == $id) ? 'selected' : ($id == old('next_station_id') ? 'selected' : NULL) }}>{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::of($name)->ucfirst()}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<input type="number" name="station_order[]"
       data-inputmask-regex="([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])"
       class="cloner-field station-order form-control @error('station_order') is-invalid @enderror"
       placeholder="{{__('admin.route.form.order')}}"
       value="{{ isset($route->station_order) ? $route->station_order :  old('station_order') }}"
       autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: set controller like return redirect()->back()->with('error_message', 'message ')->withInput(['station_order'=>'XXX','next_station_id'=>'YY']);  and in view isset(old('next_station_id'))

Comment: I have already set the `old` for the field. Here the case is a bit different. The issue is clonable fields. Which generates arrays of its value. What you said would work for a single field. How I can do it in cloned fields?

Comment: Now I got that..., you mean dynamic field, as like `name="station_order[]` is a dynamic input field here

Comment: @STA yes that is correct.

Comment: i Got that @Code Lover , In Controller Return an array to view ->withInput(['station_order'=>'XXX','next_station_id'=>Array('YY','BLA')]);  in View you check InArray Concept like  in_array('YY',old('next_station_id')); , here old('next_station_id') is an array .

Comment: @rubin let me try what you said. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeLover, this can help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57920789/4575350

Comment: @STA Thanks for sharing. My problem is how to get the index while it is non `Create` form. I can easily get for `Update` but in `Create`

Comment: it also works in create method too, if `next_station_id[]` has old data, then make a `foreach` 
 loop, otherwise `no`

Comment: @STA damn I see what you mean. Otherwise, all the cloned fields will reset to one. I got it. Let me try. Now one last point, I have a group of fields for the clone. How can you check multiple fields? Let me try what you said. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed the issue. Thanks to @STA for help.

```
// Loop through any of the field or 
// you can use for loop by getting the highest number
@foreach(old('station_id') as $i => $field)
    
    <select name="next_station_id[]"
            class="select2 next-station-select cloner-field form-control @error('next_station_id') is-invalid @enderror"
            required>
        <option>Select Next Station</option>
        @foreach($stationsData as $id => $name)
            <option value="{{$id}}"
                {{ $id == old('next_station_id')[$i] ? 'selected' : NULL ) }}>{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::of($name)->ucfirst()}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    
    <input type="number" name="station_order[]"
           data-inputmask-regex="([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])"
           class="cloner-field station-order form-control @error('station_order') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="{{__('admin.route.form.order')}}"
           value="{{ isset($route->station_order) ? $route->station_order :  old('station_order') }}"
           autocomplete="off" required>
    
@endforeach
```